# Exclude domain from Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

Some fool has implemented their Google Analytics tracking snippet on their website with **my Tracking ID** meaning my GA account is receiving data that I am not interested in from a website I have no control over. Thankfully they *are* sending their hostname with the requests:

```
<script>
    ...standard google stuff here...
    ga('create', 'MY-TRACKING-ID-HERE', 'their.hostname.here');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Because they are sending their `hostname` the data is filterable in custom reports but it still turns up in the *standard reporting*. Is there some global account setting to reject data from certain domains? I can't believe I'm the first GA user to have somebody accidentally spamming their dataset. I hope the answer is not to declare GA account bankruptcy and move on to a clean slate.

Comment: I thought there was a website control mechanism to prevent this. I've always had to upload a file or add a header for stats to be loaded. You should log in to the interface and see how to change that authorization.

Comment: Good idea Andrew. Maybe there is a force validation option somewhere. That's a new scent for me to follow, thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved this. Rather than posting the answer in your question you could actually answer your own question by posting as an answer. Then you can mark it as correct.

Comment: Users with a reputation less than 10 cannot answer their own question within 24 hours of posting it. I can answer it now.

Comment: Haha. Now I have to wait another 8 hours before I can mark it as my accepted answer. Oooo how I wish I was in my StackOverflow account where my reputation is not noob.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer just by clicking around the Google Analytics admin menus. Go to **Admin**, in the *Account* column (on the left) click on **All Filters**, click the red button labelled **+ NEW FILTER**, select **Exclude** > **traffic from the ISP domain** > **that contain**, and then enter the unwanted domain: `example.com`. Choose which views you want to apply it to (I chose all of them) and click **Save** button.

This seems to be for stopping future data being recorded. Unfortunately I can't seem to do anything about the data that has already been recorded in this account however I will update this answer if I find a way.